# Keeping selection after clicking a JButton to style text

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, jtextpane, jmenuitem

I'm making a fairly simple text editor, and I have a question about my style buttons. When I highlight text and click my "bold" button, the text bolds as expected, but my selection is not longer visible. I can still unbold the selection, italicize it, or underline it, but you just can't see what is selected. So, I'm wondering if there is a setting that will allow me to click the button, but keep my selection? I tried a JMenuItem instead of a JButton, and that seemed to work, but then it made my toolbar look quite bad. Sample code below.

```
//frame and pane creation up here
JToolBar tool = new JToolBar();
JToggleButton boldButton = new JToggleButton("Bold");
boldButton.addActionListener(new StyledEditorKit.BoldAction());
tool.add(boldButton);
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> So, I'm wondering if there is a setting that will allow me to click the button, but keep my selection?

```
boldButton.setFocusable( false );
```

Comment: This worked as well, and was much simpler to implement. Thanks.

Comment: +1, I was searching for that method, but somehow couldn't find it.

Answer (score 1):

As you noticed, the selection is still there but clicking on the toolbar button removes the focus from the text pane and hides the selection. You need to set the focus back using [`requestFocus`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#requestFocus%28%29). However, you will need to write your own action listener to add the focus code - you could extend `BoldAction` to do this.

Comment: How would I go about extending it? I tried just doing boldButton.addActionListener(new StyledEditorKit.BoldAction(){
            public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) { //Doesn't Work, fix
                pane.requestFocus();
            }
        });, but that then loses the bolding action. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: @user485418: Don't forget to call `super.actionPerformed(e);`

Comment: I knew it was going to be something trivial like that. Thanks.